# Pass crypto.js value to script nonce

Tags: node.js, express, security, cryptojs, helmet.js

I've set my projects CSP up with node-helmet so it looks like this:

```
// app.js

let nonce = require('./config/nonce')

app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
      scriptSrc: ["'self'", nonce],
      // other stuff
    },
  })
);
```

```
// config/nonce.js 

const crypto = require('crypto');
let nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');

module.exports = nonce;
```

```
// faqController.js

require("dotenv").config();
let nonce = require('../config/nonce')

exports.faq = function (req, res) { 
  res.render("faq", {
    nonce: nonce
  });
};
```

I can display the nonce as text in my HTML with `<%= nonce %>` so I know the value is being passed correctly, but when I try to pass the value to my nonce attribute on the script tag, the value doesn't seem to come through. I just get an error saying the script violates my CSP

EDIT #2:

I'm now getting this error in my console:

```
The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: 'myValueFromCrypto'. It will be ignored
```

I've seen many people recommend using crypto for nonce's... why is my CSP ignoring it?

EDIT #3:

I changed `let nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');`
to `let nonce = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');` which makes the CSP accept the value.. but I'm still not able to pass the value created by crypto into my nonce attribute in my script tag... whats going on!

I feel like the issue must be coming from `scriptSrc: ["'self'", nonce]`...  I really have no idea!

Comment: Can you show us the `res.render()` code in the route that uses that ejs file? Please [edit[ your question.

Comment: @O.Jones yes! the question has been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the issue by changing my csp to this:
`` scriptSrc: ["'self'", `'nonce-${nonce}'`], ``, hopefully this helps somebody one day!